# How to run "x" promises in parallel Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have a function "promiseFunction" which returns a promise, which is resolved at a later time.

I need to call this function many times, however I only want a set number of executions of this function to happen at once.

The function calls some external single threaded c code on my computer, if I call too many instances of this code at once I crash my system, but if I call it sequentially 1 at a time it's very slow as only one thread of my cpu is doing any work.

So I came up with the code below, however it doesn't work. It will call the first 10 promises in parallel, but slowly it starts to call less and less promises at once, until it's only calling 1 promise at a time.

```
var totalNumberOfPromises = // total number times to run promiseFunction;
var promiseCounter = 0; // keep track of which promise call this is 
for(w=0;w<10;w++){ // run 10 promises at a time
  promiseFunction().then(function(resolve) {
    loadNewPromise();
  })
  promiseCounter++;
}

function loadNewPromise(){

  if(promiseCounter<totalNumberOfPromises){
    promiseFunction().then(function(resolve) {  loadNewPromise(); });
  }else{
    alert("Finished");
  }
  promiseCounter++;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the code above that causes this behavior? And is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: I see one thing, at least: in second part of code, `promiseFunction.then` is not *invoking* `promiseFunction`.

Comment: It is invoking loadNewPromise() which is a parent function that calls promiseFunction(). How would this cause a problem?

Comment: In the top code, you have `promiseFunction().then`, but in the bottom, you have `promiseFunction.then`. `.then` should only be called on *promises*, not functions

Comment: `which returns a promise when the function is complete` - actually, it returns a promise, which is resolved at a later time - but technicalities can be confusing

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh I see the error, sorry that was a mistake converting to psudeo code. With my real code I am calling both successfully

Comment: @JaromandaX Edited to reflect your input, thank you!

Comment: see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2r9wjdh/) - if you look at the console, you'll notice that all the times are in blocks of 10 (well, +/- 1ms) - this code will ensure at most 10 calls to `promiseFunction` are "in flight" at a time - haven't looked at how it relates to your "real code", as you have stated that you've posted "pseudo code" - so think of this as a pseudo answer :p

Comment: also note in the above fiddle, there's no guarantee of the order - I mean, there is in that code, but if the promises returned by `promiseFunction` resolve in varying amounts of time, the output order can change - e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/k2r9wjdh/2/ ... but it still guarantees maximum 10 calls to `promiseFunction` are in-flight at any one time

Comment: @JaromandaX Your code works brilliantly thank you! All I meant from psudeo code is I changed variable names, and removed function parameters to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function I prepared earlier (I've used this for a few years now for just such a thing

```js
const multiQueue = length => {
    length = (isNaN(length) || length < 1) ? 1 : length;
    const q = Array.from({length}, () => Promise.resolve());
    let index = 0;
    const add = cb => {
        index = (index + 1) % length;
        return (q[index] = q[index].then(() => cb()));
    };
    return add;
};

// demo usage

const q = multiQueue(10);

let inFlight = 0;
let maxInFlight = 0;
const promiseFunction = (i) => {
   inFlight++;
    maxInFlight = Math.max(inFlight, maxInFlight);
    const obj = {inFlight, maxInFlight, i};
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            inFlight--;
            resolve(Object.assign(obj, {t:performance.now()}));
        }, 10 );
    })
};

for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    q(() => promiseFunction(i)).then(v => console.log(JSON.stringify(v)));
}
```

You can see that at most there are 10 "inFlight" requests

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? If you construct your `queue` which is and `Array` of `functions` that return a `Promise` you can `splice` chunks out of it and process each with a `Promise.all`.

```
const fakePromise = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Resolving promise ${id}`)
      resolve(id)
    }, 100)
  })
}

const queue = Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => {
  return () => fakePromise(i)
})

const batchProcessPromises = (promises, batchSize) => {
  if (promises && promises.length) {
    return Promise.all(
      promises.splice(0, batchSize)
        .map(promise => promise())
    )
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Batch complete')
        return batchProcessPromises(promises, batchSize)
      })
  }
  console.log('Batch complete')
  return Promise.resolve()
}

batchProcessPromises(queue, 10)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Time to get one with my day')
  })
```

How do you plan to construct all your promises? This function effects the original queue so you would need to ensure that the array being passed into `batchProcessPromises` isn't shared. To get around this you could potentially use the spread operator like so

```
batchProcessPromises([...queue], 10)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Time to get one with my day', queue)
  })
```

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/stwilz/2bpdcxo6/24/

Comment: If you have an array of Promises, then they've already been started. `Promise.all`'ing them in batches doesn't delay them starting. They will all run concurrently.

Comment: That's a good point @Cully! But the example I've provided still only runs `Promise.all` for the batch supplied, not the 100 promises that are created in for the queue (`.map(promise => promise())`). 

I believe addresses the question asked right?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're `Promise.all`ing just on 10 promises at a time. Once the promises are created, they'll run. So if you create 100 promises in your array, they'll all start running (e.g. when you create your `queue` variable). They don't start when you run `Promise.all`. Promises evaluate eagerly.